# What are these white bugs on my tomatoes?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, insects

I noticed these things on my tomato plants.  What are they and how can I safely get rid of them?

[image: Bugs]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the teeny tiny white bugs on my tomatoes?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/what-are-the-teeny-tiny-white-bugs-on-my-tomatoes)

Comment: altho the title is an almost exact duplicate, the image on the other question is so bad that I am not inclined to vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They look more like whitefly to me.  The way to tell is to gently shake the plant. If you see insects flying around then they are whitefly.  Only some adult aphids can fly but all whitefly can.

Neem oil will work but 5 to 10 ml of dish soap to one litre of water will also control them and is cheaper. See this [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-is-an-effective-organic-pesticide-to-use-against-aphids-or-cabbage-loopers) and [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/what-are-the-teeny-tiny-white-bugs-on-my-tomatoes/1929#1929) for details on control.

Answer (score 4):

I know what this is. I have the same thing and it took me a long time to figure out:
https://www.walterreeves.com/gardening-q-and-a/aphids-on-indoor-citrus-tree

The white things are shed skins of the live yellow-green aphids nearby. Have you seen any green bugs on your plant?

Comment: I think you are correct. If you look really closely, there are two adult aphids in the photo.